# Monero hashrates in the milions?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining

I was preparing to buy a few computers to mine monero, and we can clearly see the benchmarks on your websites.

But as I explored some wallets on nanopool, I saw hashrates exceeding 10 million.

Any idea how is that possible? Has ASIC resistance gone away? And this is only one amongst many examples.

> Between 15 and 50 million here for example. https://xmr.nanopool.org/account/8B1juYTFX9C4CMEjPZyjKvBh8h5TFZd8DbwTZPq9ggA4YVeSVavvsdN32mohei7RVHMAY5P2PnmwccKQFHQqyw1H2mJrQfj

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea how is that possible?

People renting hashrate on platforms like NiceHash.

> Has ASIC resistance gone away?

No.